# Null User.Identity.Name in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get name of an authenticated user in ASP.NET Core 5, however `User.Identity.Name` is null.
I'd like to understand how to get the user name and also how to retrieve claims, some of which are missing.

This happens with the default project.

Steps

1. Create new ASP.NET+Angular with authentication set to Individual
2. Debug and place a breakpoint on `WeatherForecastController.Get()`
3. Place a watch on `User`
4. Open application, register a new user and login
5. Click on **Fetch Data** linked in the top navigation

[image]

I've been going through the ASP.NET source code. The `name` claim is added by `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>.GenerateClaimsAsync()`. This claim isn't available either in the `ClaimsPrincipal` object.

[image]